# iCloud not syncing properly for Core Data (iOS7)

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, ios7, icloud

I'm attempting to sync Core Data among devices using iCloud (using the new iOS7 method). I'm still seeing issues with the syncing when testing with the simulators. Sometimes data from one simulator won't sync to another simulator. What could ever be the problem? Here's most of the code from the AppDelegate.m:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (!context)
    [self displayAlert];
rvc.managedObjectContext = context;
```

#### The main code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

        [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
            [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            if(!isOldVersion){
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(storesWillChange:) name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification object:coordinator];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(storesDidChange:) name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification object:coordinator];
                [moc setMergePolicy:[[NSMergePolicy alloc] initWithMergeType:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy]];
            }
        }];
        __managedObjectContext = moc;
    }

    return __managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)storesWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (__managedObjectContext) {
        [__managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            if ([__managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
                NSError *error = nil;
                [__managedObjectContext save:&error];
            }
            [__managedObjectContext reset];
        }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SCEmptyClips" object:self userInfo:nil];
        });

    }

}

-(void)storesDidChange:(NSNotification *)n{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SCDataChange" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"SCPBUpdateCheck"]];
}

/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created by merging all of the models found in the application bundle.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    return managedObjectModel;
}


/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil){
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    firstPost = NO;

    NSLog(@"STARTING to configure iCloud / new persistent store");

    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SmartCopy.sqlite"]];

    NSDictionary *options;

    if(!isOldVersion && [[userDefaults valueForKey:@"SCiCloudMode"] boolValue]){
        options = @{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"MYStoreName"};
    }else if(!isOldVersion){
        options = @{NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption: @YES};
    }else{
        options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    }

    [__persistentStoreCoordinator lock];

    result = [__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:nil];
    if (!result)
        [self displayAlert];
    [__persistentStoreCoordinator unlock];

    NSLog(@"Persistent store added. Now **%u** store(s)", [[[self persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] count]);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SCDataChange" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"SCPBUpdateCheck"]];
        firstPost = YES;
    });

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (void)mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"iCloud actual import");
    NSLog(@"insert %@", [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"inserted"]);
    NSLog(@"delete %@", [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"deleted"]);
    NSLog(@"update %@", [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"updated"]);
    [__managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SCDataChange" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"SCPBUpdateCheck"]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application's documents directory

/**
 Returns the path to the application's documents directory.
 */
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

Does anything there look wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I do it. It might be an easy way to simplify and unclutter your code.

```
self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
                            initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
self.managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = 
                            [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] 
                            initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

[self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator 
    addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
    configuration:nil
    URL:self.storeURL
    options:@{ NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"iCloudStore" }
    error:&error];
```

The only iCloud bit is the options parameter. (I removed other options for clarity.) The store URL is just `[documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store.sqlite"]`.

I am also listening to these:

```
NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification
NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification
```

In the first one, I call

```
[self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
```

and post another notification to update the UI; in the second one, I save; in the third one I also update the UI.

For me that's really all there is to it. It works flawlessly up to now.

Credit goes to [iCloudCoreDataStack](https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack/).

Comment: Thanks, I like that GitHub project. The idea of keeping the Core Data Stack in a separate class is great. Sync seems better now, however there still seems to be some simulator sync issues. Is it a problem to add new data to Core Data before the logs say "... Using local storage: 0"?

Comment: From my testing, `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` has never been called. However, I never have two devices running at once. I've seen where I add an entry with one simulator, and it doesn't appear on the second simulator. Should that notification be called to import the new entry, and it isn't?

Comment: No, it should be fired once the second instance of your app starts and there are changes. Not sure about your first question.

Comment: @Hope4You if you have an active iCloud store then it seems to be best if you wait until Core Data has switched to use that store.  This is especially true if you have data relationships that need to be satisfied.  I struggled for a while with this and now seem to have a stable operation.  Take a look at this link, and in particular the associated page about Enabling the User Interface, so far the approach has proven quite reliable. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Do you have any sample code for how to detect once Core Data has switched to the iCloud store?

Comment: Yes it's in the code I posted at the link above. Using UIManagedDocument the completion handler seems to get called once the fallback store has been opened, then you know that the next storeDidChange notification means the store has been switched to the iCloud store.  I typically then also check for the presence of seed data as well to allow for the seed data to be imported from transaction logs. If the network if not available then the logs won't get imported so your app need to handle this.

Comment: Here is a link with an explanation. I moved all This code to the OSDocumentManager now, but the logic is the same. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/when-to-enable-the-user-interface/

Comment: I just posted a sample library style app that uses the native Core Data stack not UIManagedDocument.  It includes a Settings Bundle to allow the user to chose to Use iCloud or not and handles migration of the store to and from iCloud.  Also provides the option to merge data from a device if the iCloud store already exists (i.e. another device already synced with iCloud).  http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: @Mundi Can you please have a look on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420240/core-data-with-icloud-will-not-synchronize-after-reinstalling-the-app-on-ios-7

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Can you please have a look on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420240/core-data-with-icloud-will-not-synchronize-after-reinstalling-the-app-on-ios-7