# iCloud not syncing core data on devices using iOS7

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'm implement this code https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack/blob/master/iCloudCoreDataStack to use iCloud and Core data but I can not sync the devices. I have no errors the only thing is when I launch the app I get a notification from "NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification" but not sync between the devices.

I try to leave a comment on this post:
[iCloud not syncing properly for Core Data (iOS7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503783/icloud-not-syncing-properly-for-core-data-ios7)

but I need a reputation of 50.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have just posted a sample iOS library style Core Data app which includes iCloud integration - it might help you figure out why your app is not working. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/

Comment: possible duplicate of [iCloud not syncing properly for Core Data (iOS7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503783/icloud-not-syncing-properly-for-core-data-ios7)

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Thanks for code sample. Now is working but only on my iphone for some reason the app in the iPad is not syncing to the iCloud. Any ideas of what can be wrong?

Comment: I did not post any code, you are probably thinking of @DuncanGroenewald.  I voted to close this question as a duplicate.